# How to grep for filename with literal backslash and apostrophe

Tags: bash, grep, escaping, backslash, apostrophe

I have a script which in which I am trying to grep a log file for lines containing filenames with apostrophes that have been escaped with a backslash.

My grep code is:

```
grep -i saved logfile | grep "/path/to/file/filename contains spaces, apostrophe\'s, and commas"
```

The apostrophes in the logfile all have a preceding backslash so the following grep command works:

```
grep -i saved logfile | grep "/path/to/file/filename contains spaces, apostrophe\\\'s, and commas"
```

However I am trying to run this in a if statement where the filename is a variable:

```
if [[ ! $(grep -i saved logfile | grep "$i") ]]
```

which doesn't return a match.

How can I escape the backslash and the apostrophe to get a match with grep?

Comment: How is the variable's value assigned? What does the variable contain exactly?

Comment: Figured it out! grep -i saved logfile | grep $(echo $i | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')

Comment: The variable is a filename that has been grepped from the log file. All filenames in the log file have their apostrophe's escaped, but getting sed to escape the backslash and apostrophe seems to work.

Comment: Your unquoted `echo $i` adds new and pesky complications. You're better off with a shell substitution, anyway; `grep -i saved logfile | grep "${i//\\/\\\\}"`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple layers here.  The backslash has a special meaning both to `grep` and in the shell inside double-quoted strings.  Things are simpler if you put the regex in single quotes, but then, of course, the regex cannot contain a single quote.  But you can have a single quote in double quotes adjacent to the single-quoted string.

```
grep -i saved logfile |
grep '/path/to/file/filename contains spaces, apostrophe\\'"'"'s, and commas'
```

The first single-quoted string ends with `apostrophe\\'` and is followed by `"'"` -- a double-quoted string containing a single quote.  That in turn is followed by another single-quoted string.

Alternatively, add enough backslashes to satisfy both the shell and `grep`.

```
grep -i saved logfile |
grep "/path/to/file/filename contains spaces, apostrophe\\\'s, and commas"
```

Of course, another alternative is to use `grep -F` which will match the entire string as a literal, i.e. dots will only match dots, not any character, asterisks will only match asterisks, not repetitions of the previous character, etc.

<sub>(The correct plural of "apostrophe" is simply "apostrophes", though.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

grep'ing for "\\'" works for me:

```
root@ultra:~# a="\\\'"
root@ultra:~# echo -e marley\\\'s\ ghost\\nmarley\'s ghost
marley\'s ghost
marley's ghost
root@ultra:~# echo -e marley\\\'s\ ghost\\nmarley\'s ghost | grep $a
marley\'s ghost
root@ultra:~#
```

Comment: But it returns a match even when the input is "marley's ghost" without a backslash.  The OP wants to match *with* the backslash, only.